# Blank Output and Shiny Warnings from Plotly in RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, plotly

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm using RStudio Version 1.0.136.

I installed the latest version of plotly from the CRAN mirrors, but was starting to get the following error on some relatively simple scatter plots that had worked fine before I updated Ubuntu, RStudio, and plotly (Ubuntu was 14.04, I'm not sure what my previous version of plotly or RStudio were, I installed them sometime in summer 2016).

```
Error: Variables must be length 1 or 251.
Problem variables: 'y'
```

I Googled it, and found some threads that said it was a bug in plotly that wasn't present in the version available on GitHub. I installed this version, but this didn't resolve the problem. In fact, it's made it worse. I still get that error in my original code, but in addition I often get a series of warnings, and plots (with or without warnings) appear blank in the viewer. Below is an example of a simple situation that reproduces the warnings.

```
> plot_ly(x=1:10, y=1:10, type="scatter", mode="markers")
There were 39 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::includeHTML’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
2: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::knit_print.shiny.tag’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
3: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::code’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
4: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::includeScript’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
5: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::includeMarkdown’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
6: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tags’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
7: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::is.singleton’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
8: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::withTags’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
9: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::img’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
10: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tagAppendAttributes’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
11: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::knit_print.shiny.tag.list’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
12: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::knit_print.html’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
13: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tagAppendChild’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
14: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::includeCSS’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
15: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::br’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
16: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::singleton’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
17: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::span’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
18: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::a’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
19: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tagList’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
20: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::strong’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
21: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tag’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
22: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::p’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
23: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::validateCssUnit’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
24: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::HTML’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
25: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h1’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
26: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h2’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
27: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h3’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
28: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h4’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
29: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h5’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
30: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::h6’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
31: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tagAppendChildren’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
32: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::em’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
33: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::div’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
34: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::pre’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
35: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::htmlTemplate’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
36: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::suppressDependencies’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
37: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::tagSetChildren’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
38: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::includeText’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
39: replacing previous import by ‘shiny::hr’ when loading ‘crosstalk’
```

The original error doesn't appear above, but I still get it when I run the code I was running before. Another interesting problem comes when I don't get warnings, but the plot appears completely blank in the RStudio viewer. The below code produces that problem

```
add_trace(plot_ly(x=1:10, y=1:10, type="scatter", mode="markers"), x=2:11, y=2:11)
```

Is anybody else aware of this problem and whether if it's possible for me to resolve?

Comment: I get a similar list of warnings when building my custom package... So far no idea on the cause... Did you find any solution?

Comment: I believe they're just warning that the functions listed are masked, though I'm not sure why shiny was importing. What's your custom package designed to do?

Comment: Basically some data manipulation, descriptive statistics and other custom routines but nothing fancy. I import clusterSim which somehow  depends on shiny. I noticed these warnings are issued only in Ubuntu 16.04.. so far on Windows 10 they do not appear.

Comment: My best guess as to what happened in my case was that I had versions of shiny and plotly that weren't up to date with each other, and plotly did not recognize that it was masking the same functions it would already use. That would explain why it happens on some systems/OS's and not others. Are there any errors that result, or just warnings? I've just taken to ignoring the warnings, you can silence them by wrapping the call in `suppressWarnings()`.